# Storing and removing images from core data

Tags: image, core-data, swift3

I have an image, and I am storing it in the core data (its a very small image, and I'm using external storage).
Code to convert to data is:

```
imageData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePic.backgroundImage(for: UIControlState.normal)!, 0.5)!)
```

then for debugging purposes I am trying to convert straight back into an image:

```
 let image = imageData 
 let secondimage = UIImage(data: image as Data, scale: 0.5)
 profilePic.setBackgroundImage(secondimage, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

However, when it converts back and displays the results of the conversion, the image is gone and it displays nothing, but gives no error.

Where am I going wrong to convert back to the image?

Comment: Is `imageData` valid after you create it?

Comment: @Koen - im not really to sure what you mean?  I assume it is since it doesn't return an error and the code runs?

Comment: Even if it doesn't return an error, there could still be a problem. You could put a breakpoint at the `imageData = ...` line and then check it's contents.

Comment: @koen - i managed to fix it - thanks.

Comment: That's great.  Please share the solution in your question, so that other readers with a similar issue could benefit from it.

Comment: I erased all the information in my core data, restarted Xcode and my laptop, and changed the image I was using, and it worked.

Comment: also, i changed the image type from png to jpeg.